# Prototype, addClassName on future elements

Tags: prototypejs

I'm trying to append a class via addClassName on future elements on a page with Prototype, however I do seem to struggle a bit with it.
I know of jQuery's .live feature, but I cannot find a similar feature in Prototype.

Comment: By the way, I've tried to user defer() but it's not good enough. The elements can be added any given time in the future.

Comment: Can you post a small example? are you creating the elements? you can `addClassName()` before they are inserted into the DOM.

Comment: I completely rewrote the code, making it unnecessary for adding classes in future elements. Thank you for the answer though.